# How to check last element has a css class or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding class to these elements one by one based on user input. When I reached the last span element of this section, i need to give pop up. How to check that this last span has added a css class?

```
<section id="word-section"><span class="incorrect-word-c">ਪਰਕੋ</span><span class="current-word">ਚੇਤਕ</span><span>ਚਰਚ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਰੋਕ</span><span>ਰੇਤ</span><span>ਕਰੋ</span><span>ਚਟਪਟ</span><span>ਤਕ</span><span>ਰੁਤ</span><span>ਚਰਚ</span><span>ਰੋਕੋ</span><span>ਰਕਤ</span><span>ਰੋਕ</span><span>ਚਰਚ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਰੇਤ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਪਰਤ</span><span>ਕਿ</span><span>ਰੋਕ</span><span>ਚੋਕਰ</span><span>ਰਕਤ</span><span>ਕਿ</span><span>ਰੋਕੋ</span><span>ਰੇਤ</span></section>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "last"?  Do you mean the last element in the DOM, or do you mean the last element remaining that does not have a class?  Also, what class?

Comment: Yes this last span element <span>ਰੇਤ</span> will be having the class 'current-word'.all span elements are will get this class one by one so at last this element is also getting this class. I have tried  var wordSection = $("#word-section")[0];if (wordSection.lastChild.classList.contains('.current-word')) {
                alert();
            }..but its not working..

Comment: Without checking in more depth, your comment code (btw please add this as an edit to the question) should be `classList.contains("current-word")` - you only use `.` in `.class` as a selector in jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
var remaining = $('#word-section > span').not('.current-word').length;
```

This command will find all spans that are direct children of the word-section section.  It then filters to only include those that do not have the current-word class, and get the length (count) of them.

If `remaining` is zero, they all have the class.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question

> Check if last element has a css class or not

you can use:

```
$("#word-section > span:last").hasClass("current-word")
```

this will:

- find `word-section`
- get all direct-descendant spans
- limit the spans to the last one `:last`
- check if that last one has class `current-word`

There's lots of different ways to do this, eg:

```
$("#word-section").find(">span").last().is(".current-word")
$("#word-section > span.current-word:last").length == 1
$("#word-section > span.current-word").nextAll().length == 0
```

Example snippet:

```js
if ($("#word-section > span:last").hasClass("current-word")) {
  // show popup
  console.log("example: last word is current-word");
}
else {
  console.log("example: more words to go");
}


if ($("#word-section-sample2 > span:last").hasClass("current-word")) {
  // show popup
  console.log("sample2: last word is current-word");
}
else {
  console.log("sample2: more words to go");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="word-section"><span class="incorrect-word-c">ਪਰਕੋ</span><span class="current-word">ਚੇਤਕ</span><span>ਚਰਚ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਰੋਕ</span><span>ਰੇਤ</span><span>ਕਰੋ</span><span>ਚਟਪਟ</span><span>ਤਕ</span><span>ਰੁਤ</span><span>ਚਰਚ</span><span>ਰੋਕੋ</span><span>ਰਕਤ</span><span>ਰੋਕ</span><span>ਚਰਚ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਰੇਤ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਪਰਤ</span><span>ਕਿ</span><span>ਰੋਕ</span><span>ਚੋਕਰ</span><span>ਰਕਤ</span><span>ਕਿ</span><span>ਰੋਕੋ</span><span>ਰੇਤ</span></section>

<section id="word-section-sample2"><span class="incorrect-word-c">ਪਰਕੋ</span><span>ਚੇਤਕ</span><span>ਚਰਚ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਰੋਕ</span><span>ਰੇਤ</span><span>ਕਰੋ</span><span>ਚਟਪਟ</span><span>ਤਕ</span><span>ਰੁਤ</span><span>ਚਰਚ</span><span>ਰੋਕੋ</span><span>ਰਕਤ</span><span>ਰੋਕ</span><span>ਚਰਚ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਰੇਤ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਪਰਕ</span><span>ਪਰਤ</span><span>ਕਿ</span><span>ਰੋਕ</span><span>ਚੋਕਰ</span><span>ਰਕਤ</span><span>ਕਿ</span><span>ਰੋਕੋ</span><span class="current-word">ਰੇਤ</span></section>
```